# How do i connect a curve based hair to the skeleton?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, hair, pose-mode

I tried to connect the hair to the head/spine bone as you normally would but since the hair is as long as the body and it should follow it all over, how would I go about connecting it to the entire skeleton so it follows the mesh during posing.

[image]

[image]